# Autoscale an img size (preserving aspect ratio) to the parent's div height

Tags: html, css, layout

I cannot figure out how to prevent the image (seen below) from overflowing the `div` within which it is contained.

I have tired the obvious solutions such as setting `height: 100%` as well as various combinations of `display: block` or `display: flex`

How to I automatically scale the image (preserving aspect ratio) so that it fills the height of its parent div (but not more)?

Here is the HTML file along with the CSS file. Pressing "Run Code Snippet" shows the problem perfectly.

```css
body {
    margin:  0.0em;
    padding: 0.0em;
}

.banner {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.text-one {
    margin:      0.0em;
    padding:     0.2em 0.2em 0.0em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.text-two {
    margin:     0.0em;
    padding:    0.0em 0.4em 0.5em;
    font-style: italic;
}

.picture {
    float:  right;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CSS Problem</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="main">
    <div class="banner">
        <a href="https://www.other-example.com">
            <img class="picture"
                 src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg">
        </a>
        <div class="both-text">
            <a href="https://www.example.com/">
                <h1 class="text-one">
                    www.Example.com/
                </h1>
            </a>
            <h3 class="text-two">
                The Example Application
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
        laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the `display` property of your anchor (`<a></a>`) tag that holds the image to `inline-block`. Another way is to fix the banner height by specifying a height, e.g `height: 100px`.

**Edit: To dynamically scale the picture and fix it in the container, use:**

```css
body {
    margin:  0.0em;
    padding: 0.0em;
}

.banner {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: relative;
}

.text-one {
    margin:      0.0em;
    padding:     0.2em 0.2em 0.0em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.text-two {
    margin:     0.0em;
    padding:    0.0em 0.4em 0.5em;
    font-style: italic;
}

.picture {
    height: 100%;
}

.img-container {
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CSS Problem</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="main">
    <div class="banner">
        <a  class="img-container" href="https://www.other-example.com">
            <img class="picture"
                 src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg">
        </a>
        <div class="both-text">
            <a href="https://www.example.com/">
                <h1 class="text-one">
                    www.Example.com/
                </h1>
            </a>
            <h3 class="text-two">
                The Example Application
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
        laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, hardcoding the size in pixels will change the size, but the question is how to autoscale to the parent's height. Adding `display: inline-block` cancels the `float: right`and places the image above the text (and still at maximum height). You should test your solution first.

Comment: Sorry, was not sure about what you asked. The answer is updated. @xApple

Comment: Ah, you did it! So one has to set `position: relative` onto the parent div, and add an extra container with `position: absolute`. That's the trick! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

change your css of picture class as

```
.banner a .picture
{ max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

this `max-height`,`max-width` attribute will be applied to your class picture and will work relative to its parent element.

Comment: Did you test your solution? Because I just added that definition to the CSS file, and the page rendered is the same as before, with the image overflowing. You should test before answering.

Comment: yes I have tested and have a good experience of making banner images responsive acc to device width.

Comment: How about you copy the code snippet from my question, paste it in your answer, add your modifications to the CSS, and press "run code snippet" so we can all see. Because I've tried it in three different browsers now and your solution doesn't work in this case.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/guxdzarh/3/

you can see the demo here, just added `min-width:100%` to your class picture